# Can i run Expresso AndroidJUnit4.class from my activity?

Tags: android

I am using espresso to unit test my android app. Is it possible run the test from a real device when i press a button?

It is possible that a device that is not conected to android studio to start the LoginTest.class ?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginTest {

    public static final String STRING_TO_BE_TYPED = "Andrei test";

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<Login> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            Login.class);

    @Test
    public void t1_LoginClass_Pushing_login_button_100times() {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            onView(withId(R.id.btn_signup)).perform(click());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not possible, because the test app is a whole different app.

Comment: to understand better.... i have a app that is used internally,not on google play. And i wanted a solution after update me and some user to run test by clinking a button and at the end to see if something went wrong... But if think better i can just press buttons and check result programmatically ...  i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Not. However you can run your test in a real device

Comment: can i use other automated tool to do this if espresso cant do this?

Comment: You can try the spoon which developed by Square, [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) makes existing instrumentation tests more useful. Using the application APK and instrumentation APK, Spoon runs the tests on multiple devices simultaneously.

Comment: I will not quit... is there a way to run test on apk using adb and test class

Answer (score 0):

that `AndroidJUnit4` test runner is controlled by the instrumentation... and it installs two whole different packages (the app and the test app - and the test app cannot be directly started because it's `Mainfest.xml` does not have any `Activity`, as it would be required). you could start it with `adb` (which is nothing else than the IDE does), but not from within the application package, which is supposed to be started... the log output also shows that; it reads `Connecting to ...`

```
1/30 19:14:09: Launching Test Suite
$ adb push ./mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/someapp-uni-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.acme.someapp.debug
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.acme.someapp.debug"
Success
APK installed in 2 s 752 ms

$ adb push ./mobile/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/mobile-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.acme.someapp.debug.test
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.acme.someapp.debug.test"
Success
APK installed in 1 s 743 ms

Running tests   
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug true -e class 'com.acme.someapp.ApplicationTestSuite' com.acme.someapp.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Waiting for application to come online: com.acme.someapp.debug.test | com.acme.someapp.debug
Connecting to com.acme.someapp.debug
Waiting for application to start debug server
```

see https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests